# Requisição AJAX depois de outras requisições AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu preciso fazer uma requisição AJAX depois de qualquer outra requisição AJAX.

Porém, usando o método `$(document).ajaxComplete()`, por exemplo, a requisição acabaria em loop infinito.

Existe alguma forma mais fácil de fazer esta requisição sem ser chamando ela depois de cada uma das outras?

O que esta requisição faz é puxar pendências do usuário logado num banco de dados e mostrá-las numa página HTML.

Sempre que o usuário modifica uma de suas pendências, esta é atualizada via AJAX também, porém as pendências antigas continuam aparecendo na página.

Por isso eu preciso que depois de cada outra requisição esta seja executada também para atualizar as pendências do usuário.

A requisição que eu quero executar é bem simples:

```
function sucesso(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var htmlPendencias = jqXHR.responseText;
    $("#div-pendencias").text("");
    $("#div-pendencias").append(htmlPendencias);
}
var conf = {
    method: "post",
    data: {opcao: 2},
    success: sucesso,
    dataType: "text"
};
$.ajax("logado", conf);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar a propriedade de configuração `global`.

Ela tem a função de controlar se um pedido ajax dispara eventos internos, que por sua vez dispara a callback global `.ajaxComplete`.

Assim faz na chamada que sempre é usada:

```
var conf = {
    method: "post",
    data: {opcao: 2},
    success: sucesso,
    dataType: "text",
    global: false // <-----
};
```

Podes ver um exemplo disso aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/a5u7mxm0/

E repara que na callback global, a terceira comparação nunca é `true`, e que a callback só é chamada 2 vezes. O código do exemplo é:

```
function dummie(name) {
    return {
        url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
        complete: function(response) {
            console.log(response.responseText, name);
        }
    };
}

var a = $.ajax(dummie('A'));
var b = $.ajax(dummie('B'));
var specialDummie = dummie('XPTO');
var xpto = $.ajax((specialDummie.global = false, specialDummie));

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    console.log(jqXHR == a, jqXHR == b, jqXHR == xpto);
});
```